# Fix for "Trebuchet has stopped"

Tags: cyanogenmod, home-screen-folders, trebuchet

I recently installed cyanogemod 12 unofficial version on my xiaomi redmi 1s.But whenever I try to lock a folder on my home screen it says "Unfortunately trebuchet has stopped working".I want to know if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 11):

**Method 1: Clearing data and cache**

- Go to system Settings > Apps > Open “All” tab > Select Trebuchet
- Click Force Close> Clear data and Clear cache of Trebuchet
- Restart the phone

**Method 2: Install a different launcher**

- Install a different launcher like Nova or Apex and set is as default launcher
- Since you already have Trebuchet it might conflict with the new launcher so  with root explorer or file explorer go to System > Apps > Delete/Rename Trebuchet to something else

**Method 3: Weird fix**

- Simply press menu button and you should see “Trebuchet Settings”
  ( If you still can’t find the Trebuchet settings, install a launcher like Apex or Nova > Widgets > Activities > Trebuchet > Preferences. Now you can access Trebuchet Settings/Preferences from Homescreen.)
- From Trebuchet Preferences >  Go to Dock Divider deselect and reselect it.
- From Trebuchet Preferences > Homescreen> Set the number of Homescreen to 7.
- From Trebuchet Preferences > Homescreen> Enable search bar.

[Source](http://appslova.com/fix-unfortunately-trebuchet-has-stopped-error/)

Answer (score 6):

Note: this is probably specific to latest Android 5x updates which are pushed out by Cyanogen.

You need to enable Google (Search ) App if it is disabled. You can find it in Settings → Apps → Disabled section.

[Here](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/BACON-4366) is another specific fix.

Answer (score 2):

Wipe cache and data in recovery. Reboot.

If problem persists install latest version of Cyanogenmod (dont dirty flash) --->
[CM12.1 R8 link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-1s/orig-development/rom-cyanogenmod-12-1-t3075376)

Comment: how do I "Wipe cache and data in recovery"