# Cm 13 bug regarding trebuchet

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, updates, sync

Just got cm 13 for my One plus one. There's a persistent message saying '' trebuchet has stopped ''  when I try to go to home screen from an app. Gets sorted on rebooting but restarts in a while. Please help

Comment: Probably related: [Fix for "Trebuchet has stopped"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111156/fix-for-trebuchet-has-stopped?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after the cm13 on my OPO a few days ago, but the problem seems to be fixed after I did the following today:

1. Go to settings -> Apps -> Trebuchet, click on "FORCE STOP", then go to "storage" to clean data and cache.
2. Reboot the phone.

The home page may look different than before, but you can customize it again.

Hope this helps solve your problem.